# Strange gap on the right in mobile view. How to set aspect ratio so that the logo is in centre on every screen size

Tags: html, css

I am building a website for our studio and i came to a problem. That when i view the website on the mobile device i get a very strange gap on the right.

The website is here: [www.rawstudio.ee](http://www.rawstudio.ee)

And print screen. - http://rawstudio.ee/img/ptscren.PNG

Second issue that i have is that when people who have wide but not high screens with aspect ratio for example 21:9 come on the website the logo goes very down and is not on the centre of there screen. The logo does not move in relation with the aspect ratio and is displayed to low. How can i fix it?

Comment: this may occur due to CSS styles. Control  the WIDTH in your media query

Comment: Plz, upload your code to get better solution bro.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your media queries not catching the logo when it reaches a certain size.

You just need to make a slight amendment in the css for the logo once the page reaches 370px or less and also to its container.

```
#logo {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width:370px) {
  #logo img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the strange gap is caused by the logo image, it's too large.
I suggest responsively resizing it with @media.

You can debug for mobile devices using google chrome's [Device Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGKMc.png)

As for the second part of your question, if you increase the margin-top to 50% of the `#logo img` tag, again with (multiple stacked) media queries, you'd probably get the result you want, but I don't think it's the correct way to do it.